# How to check if mysql_query returned anything or not

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

So I am trying to check if the following query returns any result or not

```
  $numUsersSameRatingQuery="SELECT * `user ratings` WHERE  category='$category' AND categoryId='$categoryId' AND  `userAromaRating`>0 ";

  $result=mysql_query($numUsersSameRatingQuery);

   $numResults=mysql_num_rows($result);

  if($numResults==0)
  {
   // do the INSERT INTO
  }
  else
  {
   //do the UPDATE SET
  }
```

However, the above returns the following error and the `if($numResults)` is executed anyway each time. In other words, I can never get the `else` block to run.

Here is the error

```
 Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\boozeDb\profileThis.php on line 141
```

Helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`is_resource`](https://www.php.net/is_resource) to make sure that it's a resource. You could alternatively use an `if` statement to make sure that `FALSE` wasn't returned.

To display the error, use [`mysql_error`](https://www.php.net/mysql_error).

**Example:**

```
<?php

// From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query() either returns a statement handle (query succeeded) or a boolean FALSE (query failed). Your code does not check for error conditions and blindly assumes success. Modify the code to look like this:

```
$result=mysql_query($numUsersSameRatingQuery) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- add this
```

Given your sample query, you're missing the `FROM` keyword, and should probably be:

```
SELECT * FROM `user ratings`
        ^^^^^^
```

I would **STRONGLY** urge you to NOT use fieldnames that contain spaces. They're nothing but trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Just like everyone else has commented, an if statement or an "or die()" could help not generating that error again, while the error probably comes from the missing "FROM" in your query.

I just felt the need to comment the fact that you're now making TWO queries to prevent some or all columns in the table from being duplicates: a SELECT and an INSERT. This could be done in ONE query and would speed up your code:

INSERT ..(what you want to insert).. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..(what to update if it already exists)..

for more info here's [MySQLs manual page about it.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)